# php address into latitude and longitude

Tags: php

i am trying to convert the address into latitude.here's my code.
but its giving wrong latititude. if i put the address manually at $final place it gives the correct latitude.however i cant hard code it,whatever source comes in text box i have to find out that address latitude. what is the mistake?

```
<?php 
    $source=$_POST['textfield11'];
    $dest=$_POST['textfield12'];
    $time=$_POST['textfield13'];
    $only = str_replace(',', '+', $source);
    $final = str_replace(' ', '+', $only);

    $url='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$final&sensor=false';
    $source1 = file_get_contents($url);
    $obj = json_decode($source1);
    $LATITUDE = $obj->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
    echo $LATITUDE;
?>
```

Comment: Maybe some more information about what you have tried?   http://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/

Comment: My guess is the value you are giving to the `$final` value is being messed up. Have you tried var_dump($final) before the geocode call to see what `$final` actually is?

Comment: If $final contains unsafe URL characters, that might be messing it up to (beyond changing spaces to pluses).  Could try $final = urlencode($only);

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `str_replace`, you should use `urlencode`.

```
<?php 
$source=urlencode($_POST['textfield11']);
$dest=$_POST['textfield12'];
$time=$_POST['textfield13'];

$url='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$source&sensor=false';
$source1 = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($source1);
$LATITUDE = $obj->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
echo $LATITUDE;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$final = urlencode($source);
$geo = simplexml_load_file("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address={$final}&sensor=false");
$lat = $geo->result->geometry->location->lat;
$lng = $geo->result->geometry->location->lng;
?>
```

Comment: thnxx.urlencode by  using xml is working.but still its not giving exact latitude,longitude value,which geocode shows.e.g lets say latitude is 31.5140 although this code gives 31.4542.what should i do now?

Comment: Make sure the address in $source is specific enough to narrow down to a region, such as postal code and country. Look up the coordinates on Google maps to see if there is relevancy in street names compared to the source

Answer (score -1):

Add a space after your `,` in the `str_replace` ... Cos at the moment, if the user types an address as "Somewhere road, That town" it will replace the ',' with a plus, and then the space resulting in: "Somewhere+road++That town" ... So something like this:

```
<?php 
 $source=$_POST['textfield11'];
 $dest=$_POST['textfield12'];
  $time=$_POST['textfield13'];
  $only = str_replace(', ', '+', $source);
    $final = str_replace(' ', '+', $only);
  $url='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$final&sensor=false';
  $source1 = file_get_contents($url);
   $obj = json_decode($source1);
      $LATITUDE = $obj->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
   echo $LATITUDE;
 ?>
```